# KO, Underscore.js: Is it Possible to Throttle Template Binding?

Tags: knockout.js, underscore.js, throttling, knockout-2.0

Using Knockout with the Underscore.js template engine...

- When I try to bind 2004 list items to a `ul` DOM element, IE8 chokes and pops up a ["slow running script" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10316957/109941).
- At first, I thought that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9985093/109941) would solve my problem. Unfortunately, it did 
  not.
- So I used [Google Chrome's profiler](http://picturepush.com/+ZphJ). It claims that my code is spending most of its time in `a.c.options.update`.

  - So I'm led to believe that the template binding is executing [over 5 million consecutive Javascript statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2345724/109941), and that I need to throttle this binding somehow, perhaps with setTimeout statements.

---

My Two-Part Question:

- Am I pursuing this problem correctly?
- If so, can I throttle Underscore.js's templating engine (inside of the `foreach` which renders my `ul` DOM element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps anyone else, the template rendering was *not* my problem.

I fixed this issue be eliminating some expensive [computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) and favoring manual subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a virtual scrolling technique since you can't display the 2000+ items in the same time anyway.

Google for "knockout virtual scrolling" and you will find some interesting implementations.

edit: https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid this one looks fine

Comment: KoGrid looks great, but unfortunately it doesn't work with IE7.

Comment: It's open source you can try to fix that, or make you own virtual scrolling code but I think it would be harder than just fix IE7 on KoGrid